# How to detection from firebase console on my an application

Tags: ios, swift, curl, push-notification, firebase-console

Now i have 1 way to do push notification.

I use firebase console( https://console.firebase.google.com/ ) and then assign bundle ID and send push notification.

now i have a question.

**How to detection from firebase console on my an application(with swift).**

This is my didReceiveRemoteNotification code

**didReceiveRemoteNotification Code**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {   
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {  
        print("Message ID1: \(messageID)")  
    }  

    var pushId = userInfo["push-id"] as? String  
    if(pushId == nil){  
        pushId = "-1"  
    }  
    fcmAccessCount(pushId: pushId!)  
    badgeCount()  

    switch application.applicationState {  
    case .active:  
    break  
    case .inactive:  
    break  
    case .background:  
    break  
    default:  
    break  
    }  

    if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary {  
        if let alert = aps["alert"] as? String {  
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "message is... ", message: alert, preferredStyle: .alert)  
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))  
            self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question correctly. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Uncleared question.

Comment: sorry my poor english i edit

Comment: You want to check the notification is delivered or not on your device?

Comment: thank you replying @iDeveloper. i want to check(detection) coming notification on my application source code.

Comment: Then you need to set break Point in App Delegate class

Comment: thank you replying @iDeveloper. i did it already but not coming...

Comment: May I see you didReceiveRemoteNotification method?

Comment: so sorry was so late reply @iDeveloper. i edit my Question(wrote didReceiveRemoteNotification method) could you make sure my code please. Thank you very much.

Comment: add breakpoint on all notifications type methods in App delegate class and check those methods are calling or not

Comment: i tried but not calling colud you explain in detail about notifications type methods please. @iDeveloper

Comment: Can you share your screen via Team viewer?

Comment: via Team viewer is remote operation tool?? if it is sorry i cant.... @iDeveloper

Comment: OK, No problem, Check my Answer it may helped you.

Comment: thank you very much a lot @iDeveloper

Answer (score 0):

**Please write this code in App Delegate class, like below and try-**

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate{




 }



    @available(iOS 10, *)
        extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

            // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
            func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                        willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                        withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
                let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
                //From here we will navigate to other screens:-


                print("User Info : \(userInfo)")

                // Change this to your preferred presentation option
                //completionHandler([])
                completionHandler([.alert,.sound])
            }

            func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                        didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                        withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
                let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
                // From here we can navigat to required screens:-
                // Print full message.
                print(userInfo)

                completionHandler()
            }
        }

        extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
            /// The callback to handle data message received via FCM for devices running iOS 10 or above.
            public func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {

            }
```